# Checking if an object is locator or ElementFinder in ProtractorJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor, element

I need to write a function to check if an object is a locator or ElementFinder. I tried to use typeof but it's not successful . Any idea?

Comment: Can you add the relevant code also?

Comment: Yup, this is difficult to help figure out what's going on. Relevant code, your protractor config, console output, error message, etc. In the current state of the question, the best answer I can give you is to read the docs. You could try `instanceof ElementFinder`. That's just a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use a function that is available for an ElementFinder, but not for a locator.

```
var isElementFinder = function(obj) {
    try {
        // you don't care about this output, just that the function can execute
        obj.getTagName();
        return true;
    } catch(e) {
        // for any object that is not an ElementFinder,
        // this should throw an error that 'getTagName' is not defined
        return false;
    }
}
```